# Extracting text from few areas on product label

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, text-mining, ocr

I'm trying to achieve algorithm that will extract text from few areas(marked with red color) on label(similar to attached image) and QR code on a single photo taken with mobile camera so label may be in a little bit different position. I'm struggling with choosing and executing good enough solution to accomplish it. I was wondering about labeling images with marked boxes around my area of intersts and then put it into some CNN. I've encounter some [interesting paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.12738v1.pdf) on text spotting but I'm not sure if it would be good solution for my problem.

I will be more than thankful for any help and suggestions. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV ?

Answer (score 1):

If the image will always be the same and your ROI will always be in the same location, then an RNN with CV2 is not necessary, you can mark the areas that you need to extract the texts. I even recommend you more like [JaidedAI
/
EasyOCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR).

Here is the google colab of the papers you sent: [Information extraction](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o8-Km-kVHtOcdEd7i9uPY6vXg7MyCN0B)